# Identifying the call context / usage when invoking C++ operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Whether what I want is bad-practice or not, I wonder if one can make a distinction between the following cases:

```
MyType A, B, C;  

Case1:  
    B  << A;    
Case2:
    C << (B << A);
```

What i want in Case1 is that B is MODIFIED such that it is concatenated with A.
In Case2 on the other hand, I want that B is NOT modified but instead  a temporary object equivalent to 'B concatenated with A' be returned (and C is modified and concatenated with that temp object).

Is this possible? If so what should be the operator overloading syntax and variants in C++? I tried r-value versions of operators RHS params; and const/non-const overloads; and also & / && post-fixing the method to discriminate LHS of overload operator.

Any ideas?
(I really tried a lot to avoid duplicate questions)

Comment: Can't you just overload `operator <<=` and avoid the ambiguity altogether?

Comment: You are absolutely right and i will do so if technically what i ask is not possible.

Comment: `B  << A` is another way of writing `operator<<(B, A)` or `B.operator<<(A)`. The operator has no knowledge about the rest of the expression, like if there are any `()`'s present.

Comment: If that is really the case, you may write as an answer and i might accept it.

Comment: @BoPersson For the sake of nitpicking, there is subtle difference between `B<<A` and `operator<<(B,A)`. The standard states: "_If an operator function is invoked using operator notation, argument evaluation is
sequenced as specified for the built-in operator_" (It is not really relevant to the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using another type.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class MyTypeHelper
{
public:
    T x;
    T* y;

    MyTypeHelper(T* t) : x(*t), y(t)
    {

    }
};

class MyType
{
public:
    std::string x;

    MyTypeHelper<MyType> operator<<(MyType& i)
    {
        MyTypeHelper<MyType> h(this);
        x += i.x;

        return h;
    }

    MyTypeHelper<MyType> operator<<(MyTypeHelper<MyType>& i)
    {
        MyTypeHelper<MyType> h(this);
        x += i.y->x;
        *(i.y) = i.x;

        return h;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    {
        MyType A, B, C;
        A.x = "A";
        B.x = "B";
        C.x = "C";

        B << A;

        std::cout << A.x << " " << B.x << " " << C.x << std::endl;
    }
    {
        MyType A, B, C;
        A.x = "A";
        B.x = "B";
        C.x = "C";

        C << (B << A);

        std::cout << A.x << " " << B.x << " " << C.x << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Just add an additional level of indirection!" :) It really seems that almost all CS problems can be solved like this... as the proverb goes.